# How to set up nginx redirect to a file with hashed name?

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, hash, single-spa

I want to use an approach shown in Single-spa's docs:

> Another option of deploying and making sure the latests javascript files are beeing used is making use of redirect (HTTP status code 302). The single-spa import map uses the unhashed url of the javascript file. eg: dist/app.js. Then when the requests for this file comes to the server it is redirected to the actual deployed file eg. dist/app.123abc.js and this is then served to the client. This way the import map never has to be updated and the microfrontend can be separately deployed.

How can I define such redirect in nginx if I don't know the current "123abc" hashed part?
I set up a redirect, but it only worked once, while that hash was correct:

`location /spa/main.js { return 301 /spa/main.58321d0246d99a5aeaaa.js; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer would be considered a "valid" answer by the Stack Overflow police, but anyway, here it is:

Instead of pursuing this method, there is a better method in Nginx.

Nginx by default calculates a hash of all static content.  This hash is then used to create the [ETag HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/headers/etag).  The **ETag HTTP header** is then used by the browser as a way to discover if a cached copy of the resource is still current.

The problem:  The browser may take its sweet time to check with the server.  Basically, it will only check with the server about the cache's validity only after the cached data moves from **Fresh** to **Stale** status.  I don't think you need the specifics about all this here, so just know this:  We can force the browser into checking every time with the Nginx server by adding `add_header Cache-Control "no-cache"` to the location configuration.

I trust you'll be able to find more information about how this configuration is done in the Internet, should this topic escapes your current Nginx knowledge.